# Reuse bootstrap modal and conditionalize text & buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I was wondering if it is possible (and, arguably more importantly, recommended / typical) to reuse a modal but conditionalize some of the content.

An example scenario would be one where a user enters or adds data for the first time (e.g. an email) and then has an option to edit that same info. In this case, is it normal to use the same modal but conditionalize the content (e.g. a header and button text) and, when the user wants to edit the data, have the modal pre-populated with the previously inputted data? Or would you normally use a different modal?

State A: [image]

State B: [image]

If it's normal to conditionalize a single modal, how would I go about doing it? JQuery?

Comment: yes. embed the info into the click element and inject before showing. like `<button data-title="edit" data-btn-text="update" data-btn-icon="fa fa-edit">` and then on click get these data attributes and populate the modal

Comment: @CerlinBoss awesome. thank you!